# where is ASP.NET Web Forms Site in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webforms, project

Is it possible to create an ASP.NET Web Forms Site in Visual Studio 2010?  When I go to File > New > Web Site there is no option to create an ASP.NET Web Forms Site.  The 2 closest things to it are: ASP.NET Empty Web Site and ASP.NET Web Site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must choose `File => New => Project...` instead and not `File => New => Web Site...`.

[image]

Then select the Visual C# / Web Templates group on the left, and then choose the “ASP.NET Web Application” template in the center column. Name your project and press the OK button.

[image]

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/tailspin-spyworks/tailspin-spyworks-part-1